# Get Div id using preg_match_all

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I have a string like below :

```
this is a testing string. Below is first div with id.
<div id='divid_first_fN8GiCLO_div'></div>
this is a testing string. Below is second div with id.
<div id='divid_second_fN8GiCLO_div'></div>
this is a testing string. Below is third div with id.
<div id='divid_third_fN8GiCLO_div'></div>
```

Required Result :

```
this is a testing string. Below is first div with id.
<iframe src="first_fN8GiCLO.html">
this is a testing string. Below is first div with id.
<iframe src="second_fN8GiCLO.html">
this is a testing string. Below is first div with id.
<iframe src="third_fN8GiCLO.html">
```

I have div id's with me, which need to be changes in iframe source's, Can I do it in some way using **preg_match_all** to get this done.. as it can be in multiple positions in string.

I need to pick ID form div and put that id in iframe and remove that div.
Thanks !

Comment: @PaulCrovella i don`t think OP requires full parse, so it's not a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


$in = "this is a testing string. Below is first div with id.
<div id='divid_first_fN8GiCLO_div'></div>
this is a testing string. Below is second div with id.
<div id='divid_second_fN8GiCLO_div'></div>
this is a testing string. Below is third div with id.
<div id='divid_third_fN8GiCLO_div'></div>";

$out = preg_replace_callback('/<div id=.divid_(\w+)_div.><\/div>/',function ($m) {
    return '<iframe src="'.$m[1].'.html">';
},$in);

echo $out;
```

Comment: thanks @cske.. this wonderfully solved my purpose.. and preg_replace_callback is something exactly what I need.. thanks again